# css animation restart when moving animated to another div

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

When changing the parent element of a div, all the css animations restart.

It's possible to animate a div while changing his parent element without restarting the animation? I want the rotateAnim of the example to only play once.

I have also tried using the **animation-play-state** property and setting the animation on the *#AnimatedElement*. Does't work either.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zs3bgj5L/5/)

Animation:

```
#AnimatedElement.animate {
    animation: rotateAnim 6s forwards;
}
```

Start animation:

```
const element = document.getElementById("AnimatedElement");
element.classList.add('animate')
setTimeout(_=> {
    const newParent = document.getElementById("parent2");
    newParent.appendChild(element);
}, 2000) // change parent element while animation is still running
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's not possible. Once you change the parent element the browser engine will re-calculate the style/layout. One possible solution to your problem is to clone the animating element, add the clone to `newParent` while removing the original `AnimatedElement` when the animation is finished.